# Datepicker: can't bind to 'bsValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular unit test, despite I've imported `DatepickerModule.forRoot()`,  I'm getting:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'bsConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
          class="form-control datepicker datetime-picker"
          bsDatepicker
          [ERROR ->][bsConfig]="myConfig"
          [(ngModel)]="myDate"
        >
    "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/DatetimePickerComponent.html@6:6
        at syntaxError node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:486:22)
        at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24674:1)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34629:1)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34604:1)
        at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:48
        at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:1)
        at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34393:1
        at Object.then node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:475:33)
        at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34391:1)
    Expected undefined to be truthy.
        at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/components/my-spec.spec.ts:41:23)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:1)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mistake is that I'm importing `DatepickerModule.forRoot(),` but instead I need `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),`.

This is imported using:

`import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';`

Comment: I'm seeing an error that shouldn't be appearing: I'm getting the following:

Can't bind to 'bsValue' since it isn't a known property of 'em'. ("iv>
            <a class="text" (click)="buscaLocalPopUp()">
              <em class="fa fa-search" [ERROR ->][(bsValue)]="date"></em>
            </a>

However, I'm importing DatepickerModule and BsDatepickerModule. I'm also  in the imports array as .forRoot()