# Can't bind to 'bsConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, components, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using the BsDatePicker and a drop down list of times in my component and I decided to move them into a custom component to make it reusable but I am getting the following error when I use it in the custom component template. In any other component, the datepicker works just fine - it's only when I place it in the custom component.

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'bsConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

core.js:4081 ERROR Error: NodeInjector: NOT_FOUND [BsDatepickerDirective]
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.js:3819)
    at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.js:13730)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.DatePickerMomentModifierDirective_Factory [as factory] (date-picker-moment-modifier.directive.ts:11)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.js:3913)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:7973)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7356)
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core.js:13879)
    at WgDateTimePickerComponent_Template (wg-datetimepicker.component.ts:19)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7329)
    at renderView (core.js:7138)
```

This is my custom component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewChild, Injector, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponentBase } from '@shared/common/app-component-base';

import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
    selector: 'wg-datetimepicker',
    template:
        `<table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px">
                    <input #DateTimePickerDatePart
                    [id]="id + 'Date'"
                    name="DateTimePickerDatePart"
                    type="date"
                    class="form-control"
                    autocomplete="off"
                    bsDatepicker
                    datePickerMomentModifier
                    [(date)]="selectedDate"
                    (dateChange)="onChange($event, selectedTime)"
                    [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"/>
                </td>
                <td style="width:100px">
                    <select #DateTimePickerTimePart 
                    [id]="id + 'Time'"
                    name="DateTimePickerTimePart"
                    [class]="class"
                    [disabled]="isDisabled"
                    [(ngModel)]="selectedTime"
                    (change)="onChange(selectedDate, $event)"
                    [tabindex]="tindex">
                        <option *ngFor="let time of listOfTimes" [value]="time.id">
                            <span style="text-align: right; width: 200px;">{{time.text}}</span>
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>`
    ,
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => WgDateTimePickerComponent),
        multi: true
    }, {
        provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => WgDateTimePickerComponent),
        multi: true
    },
    ]
})

export class WgDateTimePickerComponent extends AppComponentBase implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit { }
```

I have the BsDatepickerModule and WgDateTimePickerComponent imported correctly:

```
import { BsDatepickerConfig, BsDaterangepickerConfig, BsLocaleService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { NgxBootstrapDatePickerConfigService } from 'assets/ngx-bootstrap/ngx-bootstrap-datepicker-config.service';

NgxBootstrapDatePickerConfigService.registerNgxBootstrapDatePickerLocales();

import { WgDateTimePickerComponent } from '@app/shared/common/components/wg-datetimepicker.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    declarations: [
        WgDateTimePickerComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        WgDateTimePickerComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: BsDatepickerConfig, useFactory: NgxBootstrapDatePickerConfigService.getDatepickerConfig },
    ]
})
```

Not sure what I'm missing; any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Wg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Datepicker: can't bind to 'bsValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394597/datepicker-cant-bind-to-bsvalue-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-input)

Comment: @R.Richards Thanks, but no; I have it imported correctly. The issue occurs when I try to make a custom component with it.

Comment: Add your custom component to your module in the declarations section.

Comment: @JasonWhite Thanks but it's already there. I've edited the post to include the WgDateTimePickerComponent import.